# Why don't I see any of the terraforming buildings?

Tags: technical-issues, surviving-mars

I'm playing surviving Mars on PC, using XBox Gamepass and I purchased the extension Green planet trough the Xbox store.

The game works fine including all terraforming mechanics. However, I don't see any textures for the terraforming buildings. In the screenshot below I've selected the carbonate processor, which is working I just don't see the building.

I don't have any mods installed.

How do I fix this?

[image: No building]